# I have a problem with "Google Recaptcha V2" with PHP

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a problem with "Google Recaptcha V2" because it's always Invalid Captcha, Please Try Again. the following code that I have.

Is that the "API" problem? or problem code? or the server has a problem?

my web test : https://nexteknologi.com/test/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE0ae.png) -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epLQX.png)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Contact Form Design </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
<body>
    
<div class="contact-form">
<h2>CONTACT US</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdMM-QaAAAAACxt8fsrNCqF7HFhp-LVFOefKlt5"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Messgae" class="submit-btn">          
</form>
    
<div class="status">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $full_name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    $email_from = 'admin@nexteknologi.com';
    $email_subject = "New Form Submission";
    $email_body = "Name: $full_name.\n".
                "User phone: $phone.\n".
                "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                "User Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "anggawidianthara@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    
    $secretKey = "6LdMM-QaAAAAABsKlfpA2f4niUVM-_8DpTwYZWVe";
    $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$userIP";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    
    if ($response->success)
    {
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);                       
    echo "Message Sent Successfully";
    }   
    else
    {
    echo "<span>Invalid Captcha, Please Try Again</span>";
    }
}
    
?>
</div>     
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The allow_url_fopen setting is disabled on your server, can occur due to security measures and server configurations put in place by hosting providers to enhance the security of their servers. That's why file_get_contents function not working. You try curl instead file_get_contents.

> ```
>  $ch = curl_init();
>                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
>                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['secret' => $secretKey, 'response' => $response, 'remoteip' => $userIP]));
>                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>                     $response = curl_exec($ch);
>                     curl_close($ch);
>
>                     $responseData = json_decode($response);
> ```

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) chapter in documentation, you need to submit a **POST request**:

> - URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
> - METHOD: POST

With `file_get_contents()` it'd be something like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$post = [
    'secret' => $secretKey,
    'response' => $responseKey,
    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
];
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($post, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986),
    ]
];
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($options));
if ($response===false) {
    // Handle error here
}else{
    // Handle response here
}
```

Comment: I literally adapted this code from my own Recaptcha v2 set up. Whoever thinks it isn't useful should really provide some solid evidence. 